# Specifying model variable in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, model

I have multiple models with variables named the same.

I submitting multiple forms at the same time and trying to specify the model the variable is attached to on the input using asp-for.
When I submit my 14Plus form, the 16Plus model is still populated with the AttendancePercentage data.

How do I force assign the 14Plus model to see AttendancePercentage input as this model only?

```
Models:
    public class _14Plus
    {
        public int AttendancePercentage { get; set; }
}
    public class _16Plus
    {
        public int AttendancePercentage { get; set; }
}

HTML:
@model _14Plus

<input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.AttendancePercentage" id="AttendancePercentage"


Controller: 
        public IActionResult SubmitAllForms (_14Plus _14Plus, _16Plus _16Plus)
        {
            try
            {
                    if (_14Plus != null)

                    {
                        string[] index = {
                        "AttendancePercentage" };

                    foreach (string x in index)
                    {
                        ViewData[x] = _14Plus + x;
                    }

                    Insert14Plus(_14Plus );
                    TempData["message"] = "Success, This record is saved!";
                }
                    if (_16Plus!= null)

                    {
                        string[] index2 = {
                        "AttendancePercentage" };

                    foreach (string x in index2)
                    {
                        ViewData[x] = _16Plus+ x;
                    }

                    Insert16Plus(_16Plus);
                    TempData["message"] = "Success, This record is saved!";
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you create new model include _14plus and _16plus both?

```
Models:
public class _14Plus
{
    public int AttendancePercentage { get; set; }
}

public class _16Plus
{
    public int AttendancePercentage { get; set; }
}

public class _allFormModel
{
    public _14Plus _14Plus;
    public _16Plus _16Plus;
}

HTML:
@model _allFormModel

<form asp-action="SubmitAllForms" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
    14: <input asp-for="_14Plus.AttendancePercentage" id="_14Plus.AttendancePercentage" />
    <br/>
    16: <input asp-for="_16Plus.AttendancePercentage" id="_16Plus.AttendancePercentage" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

Controller: 
    public IActionResult SubmitAllForms (_allFormModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (model._14Plus != null)
            {
                string[] index = {"AttendancePercentage" };

                foreach (string x in index)
                {
                    ViewData[x] = model._14Plus + x;
                }

                Insert14Plus(model._14Plus );
                TempData["message"] = "Success, This record is saved!";
            }

            if (model._16Plus!= null)
            {
                string[] index2 = {"AttendancePercentage" };

                foreach (string x in index2)
                {
                    ViewData[x] = model._16Plus+ x;
                }

                Insert16Plus(model._16Plus);
                TempData["message"] = "Success, This record is saved!";
            }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, I did try this but when I submit all the models return as null..

Comment: I edited my comment and tried my self and it work. You can try it again, I think null because of input's id attribute